# is it correct way to put /web/ content of yii2 framework in root directory?

Tags: php, yii2

For hide /web/ in yii2 url there are two options:
one using .htaccess file and another to put /web/ content in root directory.

Is that a standard method to put /web/ content of yii2 framework in root directory?

Comment: Yes. And the second is preferred.

Comment: /web is used exactly for web root